# Google Hangouts Call Never Connects

Tags: google-chrome, google-hangouts

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 and trying to use Google Hangouts on the chrome web browser (version 55.0.2883.87). I have also tried installing the hangouts chrome extension. In both cases, when ever my colleagues call me and I accept the call, I just get a webcam page with myself without anyone else in the call. On their end, it keeps ringing as if I never hit accept. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

PS: I have also tried going to a link to the group call. It still just shows myself in the call. Chats work fine.